# how to use bulma offline as like bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bulma

Everyone knows how to use Bootstrap offline, simply use `<link href="{{ the location }}">`

But how to use Bulma as offline development as Bootstrap? I try with Bootstrap like

`<link href="{{ my bulma.css location}}">` but it's not working properly, I cant use `level` properties on my `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make download of the bulma css folder (on bulma site: [here](https://bulma.io/)) and put the downloaded folder inside your project, like this (for example): "rootproject\assets\css\bulma-0.6.2" and use in your html file just like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bulma-0.6.2/css/bulma.css"/>
```

>